# search for child by specific class name

Tags: swift, class, sprite-kit, enumerate

after reading [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodes) about searching child nodes I understand that I can not only search by the node's name but also by its class - by using  project_name.class_name inside the `withName` var. my project name is color and I have an class name BallNode of type `SKShapeNode`. Unfortunately I can't find the nodes using this method (As written at apple doc).in my project balls are created randomly on the screen, and each ball name is "BALL", when I search by the name (BALL) I can find the nodes but if I try by using the class name it just doest work.
here is my code:

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "color.BallNode") { node, _ in
        print("ball node found")
    }
```

does someone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link from Apple does show the correct code. I just tried the following code in a test project and it worked

```
    let ball = PushButton(upTexture: SKTexture(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "button")))
    ball.name = "ball1"
    addChild(ball)

    let ball2 = PushButton(upTexture: SKTexture(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "button")))
    ball2.name = "ball21"
    addChild(ball2)

    let ball3 = PushButton(upTexture: SKTexture(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "button")))
    ball3.name = "ball3"
    addChild(ball3)

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "WordConstructor.PushButton") { node,_ in
            print("node.name \(node.name)")
    }
```

I would check your project name that it is "color" and not "Color" do you have more than one target in your project?

can you show the code of where you add the balls to the scene?

FYI running that in your update statement will cause your game to try to find those 60 times a second which is probably not very optimal

Comment: that the correct doc - 'enumerateChildNodes(withName:using:)'

Comment: damn, I misread that...I shouldn't be trying to answer questions this early in the morning

Comment: still not working, i check everything 100 times and still don't understand what wrong. I add a photo that show my screen - maybe you can detect my mistake

Comment: not gonna give you a hard time, but you should definitely not put images of code in your question (you should type it out or paste it). it'll get you some downvotes pretty quick.

Comment: why do you have your Ball class nested inside of your GameScene class?
move it outside of the GameScene and see if that fixes it

Comment: im quit new for swift, how do I take the class outside and them implement from it?

Comment: I know but it just doesn't fly on here, the code in photos can't be search engine indexed thus the code inside the pics is completely useless to anyone else searching with the same problem

Comment: paste that code in your question and ill show you, but I'm not going to retype it

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand you. what to do?

Comment: go into xcode copy that code, come back into your question click edit, paste your code in the question and then highlight the code and press cmd+k (mac) or ctrl+k (win) to convert your text to code highlighting

Comment: I just take it outside my GameScene and its working! thank you very much!

Comment: another thing, what do you mean by FYI? how can I change it to not search 60 times per second?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159350/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-omerc).